# Commons lang StringEscapeUtils.unescapeCsv does not remove quotes

Tags: java, apache-commons

The definition of "StringEscapeUtils.unescapeCsv" says that it removes double quotes, but in my case, it does nothing.

```
String value = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeCsv(a[1]  );
```

(Value of a[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vz89B.png) = "\"Call Us\"" and the resulting value is "\"Call us\"")

See the debugger screen if you don't believe it. Is this just a bug?
[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's not a bug. It works exactly as intended. The [documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeCsv(java.lang.String)) states:

> If the value is enclosed in double quotes, and contains a comma, newline or double quote, then quotes are removed.

That means in the following cases the surrounding double quotes are removed:

```
StringEscapeUtils.unescapeCsv("\"Call \n us!\""); // -> Call \n us!
StringEscapeUtils.unescapeCsv("\"Call, us!\"");   // -> Call, us!
StringEscapeUtils.unescapeCsv("\"Call \" us!\""); // -> Call " us!
```

However in your case the following is true:

> If the value is not enclosed in double quotes, or is and does not contain a comma, newline or double quote, then the String value is returned unchanged.

That means the surrounding double quotes are not removed:

```
StringEscapeUtils.unescapeCsv("\"Call us!\""); // -> "Call us!"
```

Instead of relying on `String.split()` and `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeCsv()` you should use a proper CSV parser like [Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/).

Comment: The only difference between your two quote blocks, besides the additional two lines (first and third were unnecessary), is that you added a comma. I checked every character.

unescapeCsv("\"Call us!\""); // -> "Call us!"
unescapeCsv("\"Call, us!\"");   // -> Call, us!

Comment: Also, thanks for the Commons CSV suggestion. I should have used something like it, but I decided instead to use .replace("\"","").replace("'","") since it fit my particular use case.

Comment: Yes, the only difference is the added comma. **That's the whole point.** `unescapeCsv()` didn't work as you expected. So I explained to you **why** didn't work. **Because it only works if there is a comma** (or newline or double quote).

Comment: Ah, that is weird.